# How to remove extra quotation marks from a JSON before sending to a server in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, forms, angular-forms

So I am trying to send data that matches the model on the server side. My js code is as follows:

```
vm.answers={}
vm.formData = {answers:vm.answers};

vm.continue=function(){
       $location.path('profiles')
       if(user=='employer'){ 
           $scope.json = angular.toJson(vm.formData);
         questionService.postPostingAnswers($scope.json).then(function (data) {
         location.path("/profiles")
         console.log(data)
         },
         function () {
             alert("Error processing your request")
         }); }

         else{
             $scope.json = angular.toJson(vm.formData);
             questionService.postProfileAnswers($scope.json).then(function (data) {
                 location.path("/profies")
         console.log(data)
         },
         function () {
             alert("Error processing your request")
         });
         }
      }
```

My problem is that when I use angular.toJson it stringifies the curly braces of formData too which i dont want.
My server expects a body like:

```
{
   "answers": {
    "Q1": "A2",
    "Q2": "A4"
   }
}
```

And what I am sending with my current code is:

```
 "{
       "answers":{
       "Q1":"A2",
       "Q2":"A4"
      }
    }"
```

What should I do to fix this problem? Thanks a bunch!! :)

Comment: does sending *vm.formData* directly without ```angular.toJson()``` works?

Comment: Yes but my keys of radio buttons are not strings, I want the keys to be strings too along with values.

Comment: So your server expects a key quoted json?

Comment: Exactly, I provided an example above

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**: Don't send your Object parsed. Just

```
questionService.postProfileAnswers(vm.formData)
```

it's ok. If don't work, please pass postProfileAnswers function code.

**UPDATE**: please, make a plnkr or just check your console or share a screenshot.

Is very strange, toJson dont add `""`. Please check if your problem is not another and `""` are for debuggin proposes.

Also, if you still thinking toJson add `""`, try remove first and last character with

```
$scope.json = $scope.json.slice(1, -1);
```

Comment: The problem is my server expects a key quoted json. I already tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: Hey pablo, my console gives me this after the slice.
""answers":{"Q1":"A2","Q2":"A3","Q3":"A6","Q6":"A15","Q7":"A17","Q9":"A19"}"
instead of removing the quotes, it removed the curly braces. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you access to your server? If you can, check received data. Reviwiewing your post, you are receiving correct data: -->{
       "answers":{
       "Q1":"A2",
       "Q2":"A4"
      }
    }<-- rigth? Or you need another? If another, please paste the correct json for your server.

Comment: I checked i am not getting the correct data. I even console logged out type of the data i am sending, right after converting to JSON and it says a string.

Comment: { "answers":{ "Q1":"A2", "Q2":"A4" }  I need this, but when i console log out the type of object i am sending, its a string because of those extra boundary quotation marks. If they are not there, it would work

Comment: those extra boundary quotation marks are there just for reading proporses. this tell you that content is a string. If it was a ingenter, color was different and no quotes.